# What is coarse-grained modeling of proteins?

Tags: proteins, protein-structure, modelling, protein-protein-interaction

I need beginner-level study materials for coarse-grained modeling of **proteins**.

Can anyone supply me with entry level resources besides the Wikipedia article?

---

Background

Coarse grain protein modelling could be very broadly defined as an approximation of all-atom protein models and find current application in folding studies but are early approaches extend back to 1975.

Citing a recent review where comments in brackets are for elucidation and are not part of the citation.

> Native structures (proteins) are not completely fixed, but they change when
> proteins perform their biological function, interact with other
> biomacromolecules, or undergo unfolding–folding transitions (for example conformational changes).
> Computational modeling of these processes is crucial for ... (examples truncated). Classical atom-level
> molecular modeling can address many of the these tasks, but its
> practical applications are still limited by its algorithmic efficiency
> and the available computing power.

Kmiecik et al "Coarse-Grained Protein Models and Their Applications"  Chem. Rev. 2016, 116, 14, 7898–7936
https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.chemrev.6b00163

Comment: http://cgmartini.nl/index.php/about